# Implementation of SQL Iterators

Tags: java, sql, iterator

Does anyone know good source where I can find about implementation of SQL iterator/Operator in java and any other languages?

Comment: I think Nimesh is actually asking a very good question that needs a bit of editing. I always thought it was strange that the Java result set object did not return an iterator. Nimesh, can you expand your question? You might get more attention.

Comment: What I am asking is to write a simple database system that executes query. I am asking about how to write SQL Operators like TableScan, Join to evaluate SQL Queries without sending the whole query to DBMS.
For ex. select * from customer c,account a where c.accountnumber = a.accountnumber.
This query has SCan operator and Join operator. How to implement those?

Comment: You should edit your question when you change it.  I'm still not clear exactly what you mean.  It sounds like perhaps you have some sort of object persistence system, and you want to do certain SQL queries without using the database.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.....that is what exactly I want to do...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with Elijah's interpretation, that Nimesh actually meant, "Is it possible to make a wrapper Iterable for a ResultSet.  Here's something I whipped up.  It's obviously not yet production-ready, but it definitely gives the idea.   Since there is no standard (as far as I know) ResultSetRow, it returns an Object[] for each row.

There are some significant issues with this concept, not least that Iterator is not allowed to throw, so SQLExceptions are handled as best possible "on-site".  Also, ResultSet is a very complex and featureful beast (see for instance the overloaded methods for every type).  This complexity *could* be partially taken advantage of but isn't.  For instance, there could be methods like `getIntIterable(ResultSet rs)` which returns a `Iterable<int[]>`.  The method could check the `getColumnType`s of the ResultSetMetadata object.  That way, it could throw (if for instance not all columns are ints) before creating the Iterable, the methods of which can not throw.

```
public static class ResultSetIterable implements Iterable<Object[]>
{
private ResultSet rs;
private int columnCount;

public ResultSetIterable(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
{
    this.rs = rs;
    columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
}

public Iterator<Object[]> iterator()
{
    return new Iterator<Object[]>() 
    {
    private boolean moreRows;
    {
        try
        {
        moreRows = rs.first();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        moreRows = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        boolean knownClosed = false;
        try
        {
        knownClosed = rs.isClosed();
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
        // Ignore possible SQLException or AbstractMethodError or...
        }

        return !knownClosed && moreRows;
    }

    public Object[] next()
    {
        Object[] curRow = new Object[columnCount];
        for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
        {
        try
        {
            curRow[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            curRow[i - 1] = null;
        }
        }
        try
        {
        moreRows = rs.next();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        moreRows = false;
        }
        return curRow;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        try
        {
        rs.previous();
        rs.deleteRow();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ResultSetIterable does not support remove for this ResultSet type.");
        }
    }
    };
}
}
```